# How do i animate my 3D model to spin like a spinning coin in three.js?

Tags: three.js, blender

been stuck for hours trying to figure out how to make my 3d model spin like a coin spinning. my code is below anything help i really appreciate you guys.

```
//   add a light
  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,5)
  scene.add(light);

//  controls


 // load object
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('yattee.gltf', function (gltf) {
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
  })
        
const render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render)

    //  camera.rotation.z += .0010 

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

Comment: See my answer for some details

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider accepting and upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so:

```
let myModel;

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'model.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    myModel = gltf.scene;
    scene.add( myModel );
} );

const render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render)

    if ( myModel ) {
        myModel.rotation.z += 0.01;
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are defining the model `gltf` inside a function, which means that it cannot be accessed from `render()`. In order to spin the model, you need to define the variable `gltf` prior to loading the model, so it can be stored inside of it:

```js
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

var gltf; //By defining it prior to loading, it is now in global scope.

loader.load('yattee.gltf', function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
})
```

Then, you can add the flipping effect in the `render()` loop. Make sure that you add the given `if` statement so it doesn't crash before the model even loads!

```js
const render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    if(gltf) {
        gltf.rotation.z += .0010; //Make sure you rotate the gltf, not the camera.
     }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

And that should do it!

***Note:** I've taken a look at some of the other answers, and it seems like they either don't work, or they don't explain what they are doing properly. I think that this should help you achieve what you want.*